# Shared clipboard and Drag'n'Drop doesn't work in VirtualBox 6.1.38

Tags: virtualbox

My setup:

```
VirtualBox 6.1.38
Host: Ubuntu 20.04.6 LT
Guest: Windows 10

VirtualBox > Settings > General > Advanced > Shared clipboard and Drag'n'Drop → Bidirectional on both 
VirtualBox > Settings > User interface > Devices > Shared clipboard and Shared folders → both checked
```

I want to be able to copy and paste from my Ubuntu machine to my virtual Windows machine.

I have read some threads where some suggest updating the kernel and others claim that changing the Virtualbox version helped.

When I try to install another VirtualBox via a .deb file (virtualbox-6.1_6.1.2-135662~Ubuntu~xenial_amd64.deb) I get error: "the following packages have unmet dependencies"

Or via terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-x11
```

*The following packages have unmet dependencies:
virtualbox-guest-x11 : Depends: virtualbox-guest-utils (= 6.1.38-dfsg-3~ubuntu1.20.04.1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.*

**How do I solve this?**

Comment: I've also tried to install VBoxGuestAdditions_6.1.2.iso but I get an error: 

    VirtualBox Guest Additions: Look at /var/log/vboxadd-setup.log to find out what 
    went wrong
    modprobe vboxguest failed
    The log file /var/log/vboxadd-setup.log may contain further information.
    Press Return to close this window...

So whatever suggestion has worked for others I wind up at a dead-end.